# How to use containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation with a generic ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, navigation, prism

I have an app with two regions, one serving as a selector for data type (called NavigationPane) and the other one as a setter view for that data type (called SimulationPane). The SimulatorView.xaml I use to fill the SimulationPane has a corresponding SimulatorViewModel which dynamically creates a list of settable properties for TDataType and eventually binds it to a ItemsControl in SimulatorView.xaml. So my ViewModel needs System.Type as input:

I want to set it up as following:

```
    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<TopicSelectorView, TopicSelectorViewModel>("Selector");
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<SimulatorView, SimulatorViewModel<A>>("Simulator_A");
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<SimulatorView, SimulatorViewModel<B>>("Simulator_B"); // and so on..
    }
```

Once I have it registered, I want to be able to call (from other module):

```
regionManager.RequestNavigate("SimulationPane", $"Simulator_{topicType.Name}");
```

where topicType is the data type based on user's selection (here: 'A', 'B', and so on).

The problem with this approach is that I end up with just one ViewModel, i.e. the one I registered last. My impression is that that the registration uses some kind of dictionary with view as a key.

What am I doing wrong here? How else can I achieve my goal of being able to provide a type for VM at runtime, and navigate to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How else can I achieve my goal of being able to provide a type for VM at runtime, and navigate to it?

Register multiple viewmodels with the same view is not supported in Prism. See @brianlagunas answer on [GitHub](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1533):

> As I said in my reply to your PR, this is not something we will support in Prism. You have a few options, two of which we have already discussed; create a unique view, or have a single VM and load the relevant data.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to pass `A` and `B` as generic parameters?

I'd have a single `SimulatorViewModel` and inject a service from which the view model can get the list of parameters to be set by the user. This could be done through reflection (on the simulator type) or a list of parameter descriptors (`IReadOnlyCollection<Parameter> ISimulator.Parameters { get; }`), whatever you prefer.

When changing the simulator type, you update it in the service and the `SimulatorViewModel` updates its list of parameters, because it listens to the service's `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`.